# Recover from ZFS pool with two failed SLOG devices without recreating the pool and restore?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, ssd

I accidentally assigned both sides of a mirror to the same physical device. That drive failed, I recovered from a couple lost files already.

Here is the pool:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD nas.d20int.d20hobbies.com 13.1-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p3 GENERIC amd64
# zpool version
zfs-2.1.4-FreeBSD_g52bad4f23
zfs-kmod-2.1.4-FreeBSD_g52bad4f23
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 1 days 12:42:12 with 0 errors on Mon Dec  5 01:40:59 2022
remove: Removal of vdev 3 copied 92K in 0h0m, completed on Sun Nov  7 17:33:13 2021
    96 memory used for removed device mappings
config:

    NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
...
    logs
      mirror-4                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
        17044230459986981390  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/nvd1p1
        6464196606234086602   UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/nvd1p2
```

These commands produce these errors:

```
# zpool detach tank 17044230459986981390
cannot detach 17044230459986981390: no valid replicas
# zpool remove tank 17044230459986981390
cannot remove 17044230459986981390: operation not supported on this type of pool
# zpool remove tank mirror-4
cannot remove mirror-4: Mount encrypted datasets to replay logs.
```

This **pool is not encrypted**. The error is a mistake. This option doesn't make a different `sysctl vfs.zfs.zil.replay_disable=1`. There are no errors shown in the kstat.zfs.misc.dbgmsg kernel message buffer that are relevant. Rebooting has no issues (it comes up clean), but doesn't resolve the issue.

I opened a [ticket on openzfs](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/14259), but no one has responded.

Is there a way to further troubleshoot this? Or otherwise remove the SLOG without restoring?